# Kprobe mechanism to intercept do_page_fault

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, intercept, page-fault, kprobe

Im trying to intercept the `__do_page_fault()` method in linux kernel. The normal way to register `kprobes` , i.e. defining `kp.addr` as

```
kp.addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *) kallsyms_lookup_name("__do_page_fault");
```

is not working. What's the proper way to do this?

Edit:
Any other method of intercepting do_page_fault will also work for me.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working". Is there an error? Something else?

Comment: On doing insmod, I get the error: "ERROR: could not insert module <module name>: Invalid parameters"

Comment: Edit your question to paste the complete module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually comes when GPL licenses are not used in the module. Adding the following lines in your module should remove this error :

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

Comment: Well I find that (at least) on a recent kernel (i'm looking at 4.4.0-rc6 source), the __do_page_fault routine is marked with
NOKPROBE_SYMBOL(__do_page_fault);
macro at the end of the function definition.
Further, /sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/blacklist confirms it's blacklisted. 
So, just curious, how's it working ??